# Existe design pattern para iOS para consumir dados de um web-service?

Tags: web-service, ios, rest, design-pattern

Estou procurando um *design pattern* que ajude a padronizar a construção de um app iOS que consuma dados vindos de um web service.

Poderiam dizer se existe e o nome deste modelo de desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta curta: Não.
Resposta longa: Você tem várias formas de fazer isso, existem dois frameworks que ajudam bastante na integração client vs server no iOS.

- https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
- http://restkit.org/

Ambos tem um design pattern limpo mas que não vai te deixar engessado, ou seja, se você quiser usar seu próprio pattern mas quer usar esses frameworks para abstrair o trabalho mais pesado de networking, você pode fazer numa boa.

Eu particulamente, gosto bastante do [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html), pois ele te da bastante flexibilidade para você montar sua própria interface com o servidor e deixa-la da forma que quiser, sem se esforçar tanto.

Comment: Obrigado! Pelo que procurei realmente não existe um modelo para isso, ja que a elaboracao vai de acordo como o apo ira trabalar.